# Rotation in 3D Rigid-Body Simulator (inertia parameters, fluid drag and lift of control surface)

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, simulation, physics

My attempt to implement/port parts of the rigid body 3D simulator (airplane) from "[Physics for Game Developers, 2nd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/physics-for-game/9781449361037/)" to Javascript and Three.js seems to be failing somewhere around the rotational part: while the vehicle (body and rudder) accelerates OK it does not properly move and turn:

- At times (higher value for RHO) it appears to oscillate, resulting in "weird jerky" motion
- The control surface lift then seems to toggle sign

While the calculations are 3D, there are currently no vertical forces (Z) like gravity/lift/bouyancy, so motion takes place on the X-Y plane.

It's likely that I've made mistakes porting the Vector/Matrix/Quaternion calculations or that the model parameters are way off (vLocalInertia vectors that determine the inertia tensor are a likely candidate) or the behavior is due to the simple Euler-type integration.
Of course it's also possible the original code ([listings](https://github.com/oreillymedia/physics_for_game_developers_2e)) is erroneous ([submitted errata](https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=0636920012221)).

I'd like to be able to "drive" circles on the screen by setting the rudder and minimum thrust. Ideally, the vehicles body also causes drag and lift so it will tend to go straight and slow down if no external force (thrust) is applied.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<!--script src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script-->
<script type="importmap">
  { "imports": { "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js", "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/" } }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Euler, Matrix3, Vector3 } from "three";

/** degree to radian */
function rad(deg) {
  return (deg / 180) * Math.PI;
}
/** radian to degree */
function deg(rad) {
  return (rad / Math.PI) * 180;
}

/** */
function vstr(v) {
  return `X${v.x.toFixed(3)}, Y${v.y.toFixed(3)}, Z${v.z.toFixed(3)}, `
}

/**  */
class Vehicle {
  constructor(scene) {

this.length = 0.3;
this.width = 0.15;

this.fMass = 0.0;                           // total mass
this.mInertia = new Matrix3();              // mass moment of inertia in body coordinates
this.mInertiaInverse = new Matrix3();       // inverse of mass moment of inertia
this.vPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.001);    // position in earth coordinates
this.vVelocity = new Vector3();             // velocity in earth coordinates
this.vVelocityBody = new Vector3();         // velocity in body coordinates
this.vAngularVelocity = new Vector3();      // angular velocity in body coordinates
this.vEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); // Euler angles in body coordinates
this.fSpeed = 0.0;                          // speed (magnitude of the velocity)
this.qOrientation = new THREE.Quaternion(); // orientation in earth coordinates
this.qOrientation.setFromEuler(new Euler().setFromVector3(this.vEulerAngles));
// console.log("vEulerAngles", this.vEulerAngles);
// console.log("qOrientation", this.qOrientation);
this.vForces = new Vector3();               // total force on body
this.vMoments = new Vector3();              // total moment (torque) on body

this.elements = [
  {
    type: "main",
    fMass: 1.0,
    vDCoords: new Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vCGCoords: null,
    vLocalInertia: new Vector3(.1, .1, .1),  // TODO: 
    rotates: false,
    fIncidence: 0.0,
    fDihedral: 90.0,
    fArea: 0.5,
  },
  {
    type: "rudder",
    fMass: 0.01,
    vDCoords: new Vector3(-.15, 0.0, 0.0),
    vCGCoords: null,
    vLocalInertia: new Vector3(.01, .01, .01),  // TODO: 
    rotates: true,
    fIncidence: 0.0,
    fDihedral: 90.0,
    fArea: 0.2,
  },
];

// Calculate the vector normal (perpendicular) to each lifting surface.
// This is required when you are calculating the relative air velocity for lift and drag calculations.
for (let e of this.elements) {
  let inc = rad(e.fIncidence);
  let dih = rad(e.fDihedral);
  e.vNormal = new Vector3(
    Math.sin(inc),                  // 
    Math.cos(inc) * Math.sin(dih),  // 
    Math.cos(inc) * Math.cos(dih)   // 
  );
  e.vNormal.normalize();

  // console.log(e.vNormal);
}

// Calculate total mass
for (let e of this.elements) {
  this.fMass += e.fMass;
}
console.log("this.fMass ", this.fMass);

// Calculate combined center of gravity location
let vMoment = new Vector3();
for (let e of this.elements) {
  // vMoment += e.fMass * e.vDCoords;
  vMoment.add(e.vDCoords.clone().multiplyScalar(e.fMass))
}
// CG = vMoment/mass;
let CG = vMoment.divideScalar(this.fMass);
console.log("CG", CG);

// Calculate coordinates of each element with respect to the combined CG
for (let e of this.elements) {
  // e.vCGCoords = e.vDCoords - CG;
  e.vCGCoords = e.vDCoords.clone().sub(CG);
  console.log("e.vCGCoords", e.vCGCoords);
}

// (This inertia matrix (tensor) is in body coordinates)
let Ixx = 0;
let Iyy = 0;
let Izz = 0;
let Ixy = 0;
let Ixz = 0;
let Iyz = 0;
for (let e of this.elements) {
  Ixx += e.vLocalInertia.x + e.fMass * (e.vCGCoords.y * e.vCGCoords.y + e.vCGCoords.z * e.vCGCoords.z);
  Iyy += e.vLocalInertia.y + e.fMass * (e.vCGCoords.z * e.vCGCoords.z + e.vCGCoords.x * e.vCGCoords.x);
  Izz += e.vLocalInertia.z + e.fMass * (e.vCGCoords.x * e.vCGCoords.x + e.vCGCoords.y * e.vCGCoords.y);
  Ixy += e.fMass * (e.vCGCoords.x * e.vCGCoords.y);
  Ixz += e.fMass * (e.vCGCoords.x * e.vCGCoords.z);
  Iyz += e.fMass * (e.vCGCoords.y * e.vCGCoords.z);
}
// mass, inertia matrix and the inverse
// this.fMass = mass;
this.mInertia.e11 = Ixx;
this.mInertia.e12 = -Ixy;
this.mInertia.e13 = -Ixz;
this.mInertia.e21 = -Ixy;
this.mInertia.e22 = Iyy;
this.mInertia.e23 = -Iyz;
this.mInertia.e31 = -Ixz;
this.mInertia.e32 = -Iyz;
this.mInertia.e33 = Izz;

// console.log(this.mInertia);
console.log(this.mInertia.e11, this.mInertia.e12, this.mInertia.e13,);
console.log(this.mInertia.e21, this.mInertia.e22, this.mInertia.e23,);
console.log(this.mInertia.e31, this.mInertia.e32, this.mInertia.e33,);

this.mInertiaInverse = this.mInertia.clone().invert();

// angular
this.angle = 0; // [rad]

// [deg]
this.rudder = 8;
this.thrust = 0.1;

this.object = new THREE.Group();

this.object.position.copy(this.vPosition);
this.object.rotation.z = this.angle;

const axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(0.1);
this.object.add(axes);

// add self to scene
scene.add(this.object);
  }

  physics(dt) {

let Fb = new Vector3();
let Mb = new Vector3();

// reset forces and moments:
this.vForces.x = 0.0;
this.vForces.y = 0.0;
this.vForces.z = 0.0;
this.vMoments.x = 0.0;
this.vMoments.y = 0.0;
this.vMoments.z = 0.0;

this.elements[1].fIncidence = this.rudder;

// Define the thrust vector, which acts through the plane's CG
let ThrustForce = this.thrust;
let Thrust = new Vector3(1, 0, 0).multiplyScalar(ThrustForce);

// Calculate forces and moments in body space:
let vLocalVelocity = new Vector3();
let fLocalSpeed = 0;
let vDragVector = new Vector3();
let vLiftVector = new Vector3();
let fAttackAngle = 0;
let tmp = 0.0;
let vResultant = new Vector3();

// let i = 0;
let vtmp = new Vector3();


//  Given the attack angle, this function returns the proper lift coefficient for a symmetric (no camber) airfoil without flaps.
function RudderLiftCoefficient(angle) {
  let clf0 = [0.16, 0.456, 0.736, 0.968, 1.144, 1.12, 0.8];
  let a = [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0, 24.0];
  let cl = 0;
  let aa = Math.abs(angle);

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if ((a[i] <= aa) && (a[i + 1] > aa)) {
      cl = clf0[i] - (a[i] - aa) * (clf0[i] - clf0[i + 1]) / (a[i] - a[i + 1]);
      if (angle < 0) cl = -cl;
      break;
    }
  }
  return cl;
}

//  Given the attack angle, this function returns the proper drag coefficient for a symmetric (no camber) airfoil without flaps.
function RudderDragCoefficient(angle) {
  let cdf0 = [0.0032, 0.0072, 0.0104, 0.0184, 0.04, 0.096, 0.168];
  let a = [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0, 24.0];
  let cd = 0.5;
  let aa = Math.abs(angle);

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if ((a[i] <= aa) && (a[i + 1] > aa)) {
      cd = cdf0[i] - (a[i] - aa) * (cdf0[i] - cdf0[i + 1]) / (a[i] - a[i + 1]);
      break;
    }
  }
  return cd;
}

// let Stalling = false;
// loop through the seven lifting elements skipping the fuselage
for (let e of this.elements) {

  if (e.rotates) // The tail/rudder is a special case since it can rotate;
  {
    // thus, you have to recalculate the normal vector.
    let inc, dih;
    inc = rad(e.fIncidence); // incidence angle
    dih = rad(e.fDihedral); // dihedral angle
    e.vNormal = new Vector3(
      Math.sin(inc),                    // x?
      (Math.cos(inc) * Math.sin(dih)),  // y?
      (Math.cos(inc) * Math.cos(dih))  // z?
    );
    e.vNormal.normalize();

    // console.log("e.vNormal", e.vNormal);
  }

  // Calculate local velocity at element
  // The local velocity includes the velocity due to linear motion of the airplane,
  // plus the velocity at each element due to the rotation of the airplane.
  // Here's the rotational part
  // vtmp = this.vAngularVelocity ^ e.vCGCoords;
  vtmp.crossVectors(this.vAngularVelocity, e.vCGCoords);
  // vLocalVelocity = this.vVelocityBody + vtmp;
  vLocalVelocity.addVectors(this.vVelocityBody, vtmp);

  // Calculate local air speed
  fLocalSpeed = vLocalVelocity.length();

  // Find the direction in which drag will act.
  // Drag always acts inline with the relative velocity but in the opposing direction
  const dragthreshold = 0;//.1; // 1.0  // TODO: magic number
  if (fLocalSpeed > dragthreshold) {
    // vDragVector = -vLocalVelocity / fLocalSpeed;
    vDragVector = vLocalVelocity.clone().divideScalar(-fLocalSpeed);
    //console.log("vDragVector",vDragVector);
  }
  // else{
  //   console.log("no drag");
  // }

  // Find the direction in which lift will act.
  // Lift is always perpendicular to the drag vector
  // vLiftVector = (vDragVector ^ e.vNormal) ^ vDragVector;
  vLiftVector = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(vDragVector, e.vNormal), vDragVector);
  // tmp = vLiftVector.length(); // superfluous line in book
  vLiftVector.normalize();
  // debugger;


  // console.log("drag  ", vstr(vDragVector)); // has speed threshold
  // console.log("normal", vstr(e.vNormal));
  // console.log("lift  ", vstr(vLiftVector)); // sign toggles near zero?
  // seems ok, drag -x, lift +y


  // Find the angle of attack.
  // The attack angle is the angle between the lift vector and the element normal vector.
  // Note, the sine of the attack angle is equal to the cosine of the angle between the drag vector and the normal vector.
  // tmp = vDragVector * e.vNormal;
  tmp = vDragVector.dot(e.vNormal);

  if (tmp > 1) tmp = 1;
  if (tmp < -1) tmp = -1;
  fAttackAngle = deg(Math.asin(tmp));

  // console.log("fAttackAngle", fAttackAngle);  // toggles sign like vLift 


  // Determine the resultant force (lift and drag) on the element.
  // const RHO = 1.225;       // kg/m^3 for AIR
  const RHO = 1225;       // kg/m^3 
  tmp = 0.5 * RHO * fLocalSpeed ** 2 * e.fArea;
  if (e.type == "rudder") // Tail/rudder
  {
    // vResultant = (vLiftVector * RudderLiftCoefficient(fAttackAngle) + vDragVector * RudderDragCoefficient(fAttackAngle)) * tmp;
    
    const lc = RudderLiftCoefficient(fAttackAngle);
    const dc = RudderDragCoefficient(fAttackAngle);

    const lift = vLiftVector.multiplyScalar(lc)
    const drag = vDragVector.multiplyScalar(dc);

    const liftanddrag = lift.add(drag);

    vResultant = liftanddrag.multiplyScalar(tmp);    
    
    //vResultant.set(-0.0, -0.1, 0);
    console.log("vResultant", vstr(vResultant));
  }

  // Keep a running total of these resultant forces (total force)
  // Fb += vResultant;
  Fb.add(vResultant);

  // Calculate the moment about the CG of this element's force
  // and keep a running total of these moments (total moment)
  // vtmp = e.vCGCoords ^ vResultant;
  vtmp.crossVectors(e.vCGCoords, vResultant);
  // console.log("e.vCGCoords", vstr(e.vCGCoords));
  // console.log("moment", vstr(vtmp));

  // Mb += vtmp;
  Mb.add(vtmp);

  // debugger;

} // elements

// console.log("Mb", vstr(Mb));


// Now add the thrust
// Fb += Thrust;
Fb.add(Thrust);

// Convert forces from model space to earth space
// this.vForces = QVRotate(this.qOrientation, Fb);
this.vForces = Fb.clone().applyQuaternion(this.qOrientation);
// console.log(this.vForces);

// gravity
// const g = -9.81;
// this.vForces.z += g * this.fMass;

// moments
// this.vMoments += Mb;
this.vMoments.add(Mb);
// console.log("vMoments", vstr(this.vMoments));

// INTEGRATOR (EULER)

// calculate the acceleration of the airplane in earth space:
// Ae = this.vForces / this.fMass;
let vAe = this.vForces.clone().divideScalar(this.fMass);
// console.log(Ae);

// calculate the velocity of the airplane in earth space:
// this.vVelocity += Ae * dt;
vAe.multiplyScalar(dt);
// console.log(Ae);
this.vVelocity.add(vAe);
// console.log(this.vVelocity);

// calculate the position of the airplane in earth space:
// this.vPosition += this.vVelocity * dt;
this.vPosition.add(this.vVelocity.clone().multiplyScalar(dt));


// handle the rotations:

// calculate the angular velocity in body space:
console.log("this.vAngularVelocity", this.vAngularVelocity);
// this.vAngularVelocity += this.mInertiaInverse * (this.vMoments - (this.vAngularVelocity ^ (this.mInertia * this.vAngularVelocity))) * dt;
let mv = this.vAngularVelocity.clone().applyMatrix3(this.mInertia);
let cp = new Vector3().crossVectors(this.vAngularVelocity, mv);
let sub = this.vMoments.clone().sub(cp);
sub.multiplyScalar(dt);
this.vAngularVelocity.add(sub.applyMatrix3(this.mInertiaInverse));
console.log("this.vAngularVelocity", this.vAngularVelocity);

// calculate the new rotation quaternion:
// this.qOrientation += (this.qOrientation * this.vAngularVelocity) * (0.5 * dt);
// Quaternion * Vector
let q = this.qOrientation.clone();
let v = this.vAngularVelocity.clone();
let vq = new THREE.Quaternion(v.x, v.y, v.z, 0);
let qv = q.clone().multiply(vq);

// Q * Scalar
const scalar = 0.5 * dt;
qv.x *= scalar;
qv.y *= scalar;
qv.z *= scalar;
qv.w *= scalar;

// Q+Q
this.qOrientation.x += qv.x;
this.qOrientation.y += qv.y;
this.qOrientation.z += qv.z;
this.qOrientation.w += qv.w;
// console.log("qO",this.qOrientation);

// normalize the orientation quaternion:
// let mag = 0.0;
// mag = this.qOrientation.Magnitude();
// if (mag != 0)
//   this.qOrientation /= mag;
this.qOrientation.normalize();
// console.log(this.qOrientation);

// calculate the velocity in body space:
// (we'll need this to calculate lift and drag forces)
// this.vVelocityBody = QVRotate(~this.qOrientation, this.vVelocity);
this.vVelocityBody = this.vVelocity.clone().applyQuaternion(this.qOrientation.clone().conjugate());

// calculate the air speed:
// this.fSpeed = this.vVelocity.Magnitude();
this.fSpeed = this.vVelocity.length();

// get the Euler angles for our information
// u = MakeEulerAnglesFromQ(this.qOrientation);
let u = new Vector3().setFromEuler(new Euler().setFromQuaternion(this.qOrientation));

this.vEulerAngles.x = u.x;    // roll
this.vEulerAngles.y = u.y;    // pitch
this.vEulerAngles.z = u.z;    // yaw

// threedee
this.object.position.copy(this.vPosition);
this.object.rotation.z = this.vEulerAngles.z;

  } // physics


} // Vehicle


let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
let canvas = renderer.domElement;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color("gray");

const axes = new THREE.AxesHelper();
scene.add(axes);

const grid = new THREE.GridHelper(20, 20);
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;  // Z is up 
scene.add(grid);

let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 50);
camera.up.set(0, 0, 1); // Z is up
camera.position.set(-0, -0, 3);

let craft = new Vehicle(scene);

// simulation
let timeinitial = performance.now();
const timestart = timeinitial;
function step(time) {
  let timedelta = (time - timeinitial) / 1000; // [s]
  timeinitial = time;

  // simulate
  craft.physics(timedelta);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  if(time - timestart < 5*1000){
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);


window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});


</script>
```

EDIT: removed controls, added constant thrust and rudder angle.
EDIT: simplified code for `vResultant` - the issue seems to originate in the calculation of lift...
EDIT: `vLiftVector` has wrong direction half the time!
EDIT: never mind, that's compensated by `fAttackAngle`.

Comment: Applying constant rudder lift force and varying `vLocalInertia` several orders of magnitude does not appear to have an effect on angular acceleration (`vAngularVelocity` calculated directly).

Comment: I think you're gonna have to simplify your question by quite a bit. Asking people to parse through 600+ lines of physics calculations is no small request. Plus, the functions `RudderLiftCoefficient` and `Drag` are borderline inscrutable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @Marquizzo I know, that's why I am going to offer a bounty asap to make it worth their while. And you are right of course, I might be able to boil it down even further, although omitting the input and visualization will remove the chance to "get a feel". The coefficient functions simply interpolate empirical data points, but I might simplify them as well.

Comment: @Marquizzo I've removed some code, but left the Coefficient functions to show the "jerky" motion. Setting `vResultant` manually (uncomment) eliminates jerky motion and shows minimal effect of torque on angular velocity.

Comment: I appreciate any hints on further reducing the code!

Comment: Looks like it might be the integrator - depending on parameters and timestep, at higher velocity it can start to oscillate and the calculations eventually "explode" (NaN).